# Converting and combining 2 Python files into one exe doesn't work

Tags: python, pyinstaller, exe, converters, keylogger

I recently worked on a keylogger script which sends keystrokes to email, I have 2 python files:
The main one which is the keylogger and the second which has the functions to send the keystrokes by email.

I tried to convert both of the files to exe using the pyinstaller command: "`pyinstaller main.py email.py --onefile`" and it worked perfectly, but when I went to the exe file that was created and opened it the command prompt opened and closed and the code doesn't work. I tried to combine both files but it didn't work.

Comment: Normally you tell `pyinstaller` about your main file and it figures out which others to include based on imports.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the command is like this: pyinstaller --onefile 1stfile.py 2ndfile.py

Comment: Nope. still doesn't work :/ It opens and close the cmd, but when i run it only the python file i have output and all. Il try to add second code to the first.